# How to get histogram data in measuring the performance

Tags: java, histogram

I am trying to measure the performance of our service by putting the data in a HashMap like-
`X` number of calls came back in `Y` ms. Below is my code which is very simple. It will set the timer before hitting the service and after the response came back, it will measure the time.

```
private static void serviceCall() {

    histogram = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
    keys = histogram.keySet();
    long total = 10;
    long runs = total;

    while (runs > 0) {

        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // hitting the service      
        result = restTemplate
                .getForObject("Some URL",String.class);

        long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);

        Long count = histogram.get(difference);
        if (count != null) {
            count++;
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), count);
        } else {
            histogram.put(Long.valueOf(difference), Long.valueOf(1L));
        }
        runs--;
    }
    for (Long key : keys) {
        Long value = histogram.get(key);
        System.out.println("SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, " + key + ":" + value);
    }
}
```

Currently the output I am getting is something like this-

```
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 166:1
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 40:2
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 41:4
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 42:1
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 43:1
SERVICE MEASUREMENT, HG data, 44:1
```

which means is `1 call came back in 166 ms`, `2 calls came back in 40 ms` and same with other outputs.

**Problem Statement:-**

What I am looking for now is something like this. I should have range setup like this-

```
X Number of calls came back in between 1 and 10 ms
Y Number of calls came back in between 11 and 20 ms
Z Number of calls came back in between 21 and 30 ms
P Number of calls came back in between 31 and 40 ms
T number of calls came back in between 41 and 50 ms

....
....

I number of calls came back in more than 100 ms
```

And any way to configure the range also. Suppose in future I need to tweak in the range, I should be able to do it. How can I achieve this thing in my current program? Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A histogram is a set of data arranged into "bins" of equal size.  You should convert your time measurement to a bin and use that bin as the map key.  This can be done simply by dividing your time value by the bin size.  For example:  `time / 10L`.

Comment: Thanks JimN for the suggestion. Can you provide me any example that can split into the groups I am looking for. By that I can understand more. Thanks for the help.